# QTextStream and Visual Studio 2008 release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, release

I have a simple code using QTextStream and it works very fine in visual studio in debug mode, but if I put it in release mode it doesn`t read anything from the file. I included QtCore4.lib for the release mode and for the debug mode QtCored4.lib. I`m using Qt4.6.3 vs2008,what could be the problem if it works in debug mode?
I insert the code below:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iterator>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{

 QString qsArgsFile = "curexp.txt",line;
 QByteArray baline;
 cout<<qsArgsFile.toAscii().data();
 QFile qfile( qsArgsFile );
    assert(qfile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text));
    QTextStream stream( &qfile );
 baline = qfile.read(50);
 const char *liner;
    while(!(line = stream.readLine()).isNull()) 
      if (!line.isEmpty()) {
    baline = line.toLatin1();
    liner = baline.data();
        cout << liner << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you put code with side-effects into an assert:

```
assert(qfile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text));
```

This code is never executed in release mode. Not only are assertions disabled, also the code inside them is not executed! Rule: Never put anything with side-effects inside an assert(). This is the first thing to look for when something works in debug mode but not in release mode.

If you want to assert, do it like this:

```
const bool opened = qfile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
assert( opened );
```

Comment: Everyone does this at least once. Asserts are useful, but slightly evil as well.

Comment: Yes, never assert() on conditions outside of the application's control - like file system state, input data, user actions etc. But this issue can of course also happen with completely valid usages of assert().

Comment: Thanks for help! This solved my problem, I didn`t know that assert is skipped in release mode.